# C3 WPF Caliburn Dapper ComboBox SelectedItem not returning the correct value

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, caliburn.micro, selecteditem

My colleque and have spent a lot of hours on how to get the correct in value in the DataGrid.
We can see the returned value is returning 2 values but how do we define we only want one of the values saved?

**The CombBox in the xaml (loading a stored procedure to fill the combobox):**

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding TKS_Valgmuligheder}" SelectedItem="{Binding ValgtTKSStatus}">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TKSValg}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

**The property item:**

```
private TKSValgModel _valgtTKSStatus;
    public TKSValgModel ValgtTKSStatus
    {
        get { return _valgtTKSStatus; }
        set
        {
            _valgtTKSStatus = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ValgtTKSStatus);
        }
    }
```

**The Model class**

```
public class TKSValgModel
    {
        public int TKS_Id { get; set; }
        public string TKSValg { get; set; }
    }
```

**Screen dump of Debugging**

[Screen dump of debugging showing a string and an int](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2nNl.png)

We are only interesseted in saving the string value (no.1) to our database and be shown in the grid when loaded. Instead we get the text above (no.2)

[Screen dump of what is saved and shown in the DataGrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIjfo.png)

Update
The DataGridColumnis defined as following:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="TKS-Status" Binding="{Binding Path=TKSStatus}"></DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: Hi the DataGridColumn defined as following :
<DataGridTextColumn Header="TKS-Status" Binding="{Binding Path=TKSStatus}"></DataGridTextColumn> I actually added it to my original post to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

We figured it out!
We added it to the sql query:

```
 connection.Execute($"spUpdatePatient @TKSStatus = '{ValgtTKSStatus.TKSValg}', @CPR= '{CprTextBox}', @NyBrevDato='{null}' ");
```